# How to burn MP3 files?

Tags: brasero, k3b

Is there a way to burn .mp3 music on CD in Ubuntu 11.10? There is Brasero installed but I also installed k3b.

Answer (score 9):

In brasero, you should be able to select new audio project, then drag and drop files.[image: Freshly opened Brasero]

[image: Drag files from nautilus window.]

Of course you'll probably notice the files I'm using in this example are .ogg. 
 
That's just another format for multimedia files. You'll want to drag .mp3 files since it sounds like you want them to play on a device that supports mp3.

Comment: Yes, that's main problem. I wasn't sure if CD burned on this way will play on device that supports mp3. Thanks I will try this.

Comment: Some devices support CD's burnt this way, some do not. There should be an mp3 logo somewhere on the device if it will.

Comment: It tells that I burn this on several CDs. It's obvious that this tries to burn audio CD which is 80 minute length and approximately 20 songs, but I want to burn mp3 CD to play for example in car. Where I burn mp3 CD in Windows with Nero then I have possibility to put about 200 songs.

Comment: I that case, you could try to burn a 'data project', but I doubt it will play in a car CD player. I suppose it's worth a try. Only costs you a CD.

Comment: No it will not work, I tried this with Nero earlier on Windows.

Comment: Ok. That's what I thought. Sounds like you'll need to make multiple audio CD's or use another device to interface with your radio. For example an mp3 player with an FM transmitter if you don't have an AUX port.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1687/discussion-between-argusvision-and--)

Answer (score 6):

If your CD player can play MP3 CDs, you can create a Data Project in Brasero and copy your MP3s onto the CD as regular files. This allows you to fit 100--200 songs on a CD depending on their quality.

BUT, different players have different limitations on things like filenames, limits of subdirectories, etc. so it may take some experimenting to figure out what your MP3 CD player can and cannot play.

Otherwise, if your CD player does not support MP3s, you're stuck with regular audio CDs (80 minutes).

Comment: My CD player supports MP3s. I will try with Data project.

Answer (score 3):

Just use Asunder. `sudo apt-get install asunder`. It works out of the box with fixed (up to 320 kbps) and variable bitrates. Though, I did have to go to preferences and change the CD-ROM device to `/dev/sr0`.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I have burnt many mp3 files with K3b to data disc and played them in a car cd/mp3 player. I always burnt these mp3 files to a **data** disc
however recently I tried to do it again and had unplayable discs.
i realised that the file format was incorrect and had success when i Changed the format from Linux/unix +windows to **Custom - Rock ridge/joliet** format.This can be selected after clicking the burn button and clicking on filesystem, then scroll down to "Custom ( Rock ridge / joliet )selecting that item.
Then after burning them as data discs they will playable on a CD/mp3 player. 
I like to use easytag prior to burning mp3s so that these tags show on player screen as artist and track