# How do I burn Mp3 files in to a CD so I can listen them in my stereo?

Tags: music, cd

I have 65 music in Mp3 format. I want to burn these music for a CD-R to play it with my stereo system.

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Does your stereo support Mp3 format or do you want to convert all the Mp3s to audio CD and record several CDs with the music?\

Comment: If you want to create a traditional Audio then take a look at this question [How to burn MP3 files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74090/how-to-burn-mp3-files?rq=1).  Some CD players however also support MP3 files so you just need to copy the files to the CD.

Comment: @Bruno Pereira: Yes. I think my stereo support mp3.

Comment: You can download some CD/DVD burning softwares from software center like CD/DVD Maker. Use those tools to create a disk.

Comment: @Yedhu Krishnan: I tried K3b but it doesn't worked because it convert my mp3 to .ogg. I tried DeepBurner on Win7 but every time it gave me an error. I tried Windows media player but It burnt only 19 song for my cd. So I tried many software but they didn't work for me. I don't want to crack more CD.

Comment: @Yedhu Krishnan: I'll try the CD/DVD maker. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 11):

Brasero, the default CD/DVD burning software, should be capable of this regardless of whether your stereo is mp3 compatible or not (try both, CDR media is cheap..)

For an MP3 CD, use "Data project". For an audio disk, use "Audio project".

Comment: I succesfully burnt my musics to the CD. I used Brasero's Data Project. It works with my Stereo and my e:max DVD Player but it doesn't work with my Xbox 360 Slim.